# sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider could not be instantiated

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaagents

I'm currently writing an attacher which attaches agents to JVM processes, and I keep running into this issue. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```java
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;

public class AgentAttacher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String pid = "some-pid-determined-elsewhere";
            final VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
            vm.loadAgent("agent.jar");
            vm.detach();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When running `java -jar AgentAttacher.jar`, I get the following error:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.attach.spi.AttachProvider: Provider sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider could not be instantiated
```

I have tried adding `tools.jar` from the `lib` directory of my JDK to the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, including it in the `Class-Path` in my `MANIFEST.MF`, and directly specifying it using `-cp` while running the JAR. I'm fairly certain that `tools.jar` is being loaded because it gives a different error when missing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine
```

I'm also getting the `WindowsAttachProvider could not be instantiated` error while only using `VirtualMachine.list()`, so I don't think this is related to using `attach()` with an incorrect PID.

---

I've tried loading the class using `Class.forName()`:

```java
public class AgentAttacher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and I get the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no attach in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider.<clinit>(WindowsAttachProvider.java:175)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at JavaAttacker.main(JavaAttacker.java:4)
```

If I don't include `tools.jar` in the classpath, I get a different stack trace here, so I'm sure it's being loaded:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at JavaAttacker.main(JavaAttacker.java:4)
```

---

My environment is a Windows 10 Pro (1809) VM on VirtualBox with JDK & JRE 1.8.0_212.

Comment: Try `Class.forName("sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider")`, just to see whether you get a better stack trace.

Comment: I've added the stack trace for that to the original question, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the issue was with `attach.dll` not loading from `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin`.

Running the jar as:

```
java -Djava.library.path="%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin" -jar AgentAttacher.jar
```

appears to have worked, so long as `tools.jar` is specified in my jar manifest under `Class-Path`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, the attach API is part of a seperate jar that the JVM does not load by default. You will have to include it explicitly in the class path. Typically, it is located in the `\lib` folder of your JDK's home:

```
java -cp %JAVA_HOME%\\lib\\tools.jar -jar AgentAttacher.jar
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael. Unfortunately, I've already tried including `tools.jar` with the `-cp` flag while running the jar. I get a different error (can't find classes) when not including it, so I'm fairly certain it's being loaded.

Comment: Normally, the attach methods takes a String where you provide an integer. Maybe you have your sources confused.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! My actual code uses a string, but I've transcribed it incorrectly here. I've changed the code to reflect this.

Comment: The exception you are getting indicates that the attach provider cannot be instantiated. Do you have a stack trace to that?

Comment: The exception is being printed via `e.printStackTrace()`, so that is the complete stack trace, unless I'm missing something!

Comment: Then the native code throws the exception. Are you sure you installed the right JDK?

Comment: …or that it *is* actually a JDK and not a JRE…

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and solved it this way:

use jdk 11 build source,can not find `tools.jar`  or tools.jar is windows

this is my pom.xml

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
      <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

```bash
# Create a local directory and put tools. jar in it
mkdir lib && cp %JAVA_8_HOME/lib/tools.jar% lib/
```

then:

```bash
mvn package
java -jar attach-agent.jar
```