# Provider sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider not found

Tags: java, jvm, tools.jar

I am trying to compile an app with java 8 and run it with java 17.

I have both in my machine installed - java 8 and java 17.
Java 8 set as $JAVA_HOME and java 17 has its own variable $JDK170_HOME.

I compiled application with java 8, added vm parameter to run it with java 17.
Also i added

> -Djava.library.path="%JAVA_HOME%\lib"

to add tools.jar from jdk8 to runtime jdk17 to my path.

but in stdOut.log I see

```
 java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
 com.sun.tools.attach.spi.AttachProvider: Provider
 sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider not found
```

Please tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider could not be instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57006881/sun-tools-attach-windowsattachprovider-could-not-be-instantiated)

Comment: You should not mess around with the `java.library.path` property. Neither should you add the `tools.jar` of one Java installation to another. JDK 17 ships with its own implementation of the APIs contained in tools.jar. Does you application even use any of them? And whatever “vm parameter” you added, it’s likely to be unnecessary as well.

Comment: @aled yes, i mentioned this above. I tried, it didn't help. And also there was another problem - could not be instantiated (in my case - not found)

Comment: @Holger i know, that the best solution is to compiler with java17 either. But i required to compile with java8. Speaking about vm parameter - i meant java.vm.version, but it's not so important in my question i think

Comment: Please provide more details on the code you are trying to build and it needs un.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.

Comment: It doesn’t matter which version you use for compiling. When you *run* it on JDK 17, you should not modify the `java.library.path` and not add a `tools.jar` from another JDK to it. Neither is necessary.

Comment: @aled it seems that ehcache uses it for reflection

Comment: That is information that should be in the question. It seems that a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is missing.